# The difference between "come out winners" and "come out as winners"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Could you explain to me what is the difference between "come out winners" and "come out as winners"? Are they both ok to use?

Comment: They're both fine. In principle the ***as*** version could imply *not **actually** - just **like** winners*, and that could make a difference in some utterances using basically the same construction. But in the specific example here that's a meaningless distinction (coming out *like* a winner means you *are* a winner).

Answer (score 1):

**There is no difference.**

Both are acceptable and commonly used.

Answer (score -2):

Come out winners is a command.

> Come out wherever you are!

> Come out child.

*As* means to *be like*.

> Acted as a cobra.

Coming out *as* winners means to be like a winner, to resemble a winner.

Comment: So when I say "they come out winners whenever they participate in the contest," I'm giving a command?

Comment: Well, in this case, you should use 'as winners'. This version makes much more sense.

Additionally, If you put a subject before a command phrase, it is no longer a command. "Eat your dinner", is not the same as "Sally eats her dinner".

  Commands usually start with a verb and aren't used in complex sentences.
It's (verb) + (what you want someone to do)>

Please look at this site for more examples: https://preply.com/en/question/command-sentences-in-english